# What could be causing different behaviour remotely on asp.net site

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a site that I have developed in asp.net. On debugging the site now hosted using IIS7 I noticed a bug, I cannot reproduce this when I run it locally in vs, meaning I can't see the error. The bug occurs on the check box changed event of a devexpress check box. It connects to the database using devart.postgres sql component and linq. However, this is the same connection as anywhere else in the project. The same code works elsewhere in the project. The error I get is:

> the requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.

Part of my code is in an if statement that checks if a textbox is blank if so it does not run the code within the if statement, interestingly enough if the text box is blank the code runs, so it must be in the if statement? I commented out all of the code and tried again and it still would not run. Beginning to lost objectivity with this problem, hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you have posted suggests that there is a problem resolving an address. For example, when you check that checkbox, something in your code tries to resolve a valid address, but the DNS server doesn't recognise it. Are you doing anything that would involve name resolution?

Can you share the code that causes this error?

Comment: thank you for your answer, I was an absolute muppet and i forgot to change the dll's when uploading. Problem sorted now, thank you. for your answer.